# how do i set an id of an input field created dynamically?

Tags: jquery

I have form fields which has inputs that are created dynamically on demand by a user, from those inputs fields i use their id's  to perform live search but now the id's of the inputs created dynamically are same through out which then makes me unable to use their id's to search because they are the same so how can set different id for those inputs that are appended by the user? here is my code

```
 $("#new_encounter").click(function(){

        $("#client_info").html('<div class="table-responsive" id="div_data"><form name="add_me" id="add_me" class="form-inline" ><table id="dynamic" class="table table-bordered"><tr class="info"><th width="70%">DIAGNOSIS</th><th>ICD 10 CODE</th><tr class="info"><tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="diagnosis[]" id="diagnosis" style="width:350px;" placeholder="Enter Diagnosis Keyword"/><div id="diagnosis_list"></div></td>    <td><input type="text"  class="form-control" name="code[]" id="code" placeholder="ICD10 CODE"/></td><td><button type="button" name="add" id="add_input" class="btn  btn-success">Add</button></td></tr></table><center><input type="button" name="create_program" id="create_program" class="btn  btn-success" value="SAVE"/></center></form></div>');
              var i=1;
$('#add_input').click(function(){
i++;

$('#dynamic').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="diagnosis[]" id="diagnosis2" style="width:350px;" placeholder="Enter Diagnosis Keyword"/><div id="diagnosis_list2"></div></td>    <td><input type="text"  class="form-control" name="code[]" id="code2" placeholder="ICD10 CODE"/></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn_remove btn btn-danger">Remove</button></td></tr>');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the same thing as you are doing with the thr id elements, pass the i index in the id attribute

```
$('#dynamic').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="diagnosis[]" id="diagnosis' + i + '" style="width:350px;" placeholder="Enter Diagnosis Keyword"/><div id="diagnosis_list' + i +'"></div></td>    <td><input type="text"  class="form-control" name="code[]" id="code' + i + '" placeholder="ICD10 CODE"/></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn_remove btn btn-danger">Remove</button></td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: i feel really stupid for asking this question now. But thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<input />").attr('id', ... );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$("#new_encounter").click(function(){
  $("#client_info").html('<div class="table-responsive" id="div_data"><form name="add_me" id="add_me" class="form-inline" ><table id="dynamic" class="table table-bordered"><tr class="info"><th width="70%">DIAGNOSIS</th><th>ICD 10 CODE</th><tr class="info"><tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="diagnosis[]" id="diagnosis" style="width:350px;" placeholder="Enter Diagnosis Keyword"/><div id="diagnosis_list"></div></td>   <td><input type="text"  class="form-control" name="code[]" id="code" placeholder="ICD10 CODE"/></td><td><button type="button" name="add" id="add_input" class="btn  btn-success">Add</button></td></tr></table><center><input type="button" name="create_program" id="create_program" class="btn  btn-success" value="SAVE"/></center></form></div>');
});

var i=1;
$(document).on('click', '#add_input', function(){
  i++;
  $('#dynamic').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="diagnosis[]" id="diagnosis2" style="width:350px;" placeholder="Enter Diagnosis Keyword"/><div id="diagnosis_list2"></div></td>    <td><input type="text"  class="form-control" name="code[]" id="code2" placeholder="ICD10 CODE"/></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn_remove btn btn-danger">Remove</button></td></tr>');
});

$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="client_info"></div>

<button id="new_encounter">Click Me!!!</button>
```

You can't have the `#add_input` click event inside the `#new_encounter` click.

Since `#add_input` button is getting dynamically added, so you need to use event delegation.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks but that does really solve what i was looking for as the id of the fields appended remains the same